# Function After AJAX Call

Tags: jquery

I  have the following AJAX call which is working ok as the data retrieved is posted to a PHP and it appears in the database. However after the post request nothing fires in the function call immediately after.

In the code below I have placed a simple alert("Test") command in their to test and this does not fire either.

Similar code does work on other pages but this is the first page that I have configured to use JQuery UI, could this be the problem?

I am using jquery v1.9.1.

```
 function  CreateNewStaff(str, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6){
            $.post('scripts/dbc_AddNewStaff.php', { staffid:str, username:str2, firstname:str3, lastname:str4, password:str5, accesslevel:str6 },
            function(data){ 
            alert("Test");
            jsResponse =  trim_ws(data.Response);
            if (jsResponse  === 'Success')      
                {
                alert("Test");
                }
        }, "json");
    }
```

Comment: What is `trim_ws(x)`? Is it an equivalent to `x.trim()`?

Comment: It's just a function to trim whitespace from the end of any data that is returned.

Comment: Apart from the non-semantic variable names and broken indentation (and inconsistent brace style) and assuming the `alert` is there for debugging purposes only, I can't see anything wrong here. Does the server really return `'Success'`?

Comment: Yes the alert is there only for debugging purposes. The server script does return a value of 'Success'. Other comments taken on board but in my defense I have to say that I am very new to this and currently on a very steep learning curve.

Comment: The unfamiliarity with syntax is no excuse for naming your arguments `str`..`str6` :-)

Comment: I agree. Point taken. Is there any further debugging I can do to find out why this is not working. If I place the alert before the function(data) call it fires ok.